# Show/hide tablesorter sticky header

Tags: jquery, css, tablesorter

I have no problems with my tablesorter or sticky headers at all, but I have three large tables on my website, two of them hidden by default with **"display:none"**.
One table should be shown by clicking a link and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $(".single-phone-ht2").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop : 0},0);
        // tables to show and hide
        $("#single-mob-ft").hide();
        $("#single-mob-ht1").hide();
        $("#single-mob-ht2").show();
        // extra class name added to the sticky header row
        $(".sh-ft").hide();
        $(".sh-ht1").hide();
        $(".sh-ht2").show();
        // buttons to click
        $(".single-phone-ft-li").show();
        $(".single-phone-ht1-li").show();
        $(".single-phone-ht2-li").hide();
    });
});
```

Works, tables are shown and hidden as planned, but as soon as tables are scrolled and sticky headers show up, those sticky headers still show up when the table is shown again after those other two have been displayed in the meantime. I thought scrolling the page to the top would solve it, but... it doesn't. Of course the sticky headers disappear as soon as I scroll manually.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: If the sticky headers are clones of the real headers, you may have to show/hide them manually.

Comment: If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), all you should need to do is show/hide the table itself - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/273/). If you aren't using it, then please provide a demo... or the HTML that matches the above code.